# IPTables drop UDP packets with IP Header Identification

Tags: linux, networking, udp, iptables, ddos

We are currently receiving a 30Mbps Spoofed UDP flood against one of our applications that is causing high CPU usage, we have a dedicated firewall running a basic version of linux with IPTables.

Looking at the traffic logs, all of the spoofed UDP traffic has a header identification number of 31336. Is it possible to drop packets matching this number via IPTables?

Here is a picture containing a wireshark capture showing the identification number:
[image]

The data inside of the UDP packet is also between 90 and 800 bytes which replicates legitimate traffic into our application. The ident number is the only way I can see of matching the bad traffic.

Comment: There is an example [here](http://www.stearns.org/doc/iptables-u32.current.html) (I have never tried it though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to use iptables' [u32 extension](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO-3.html#ss3.21).

This was not tested by me personally, but the rule should look something like this:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -p udp -m u32 --u32 "2&0xFFFF=0x7a68" -j DROP
```